# Failed to parse date in DateFormat.FULL

Tags: java, date-format

How do I parse a date string like "Sun Feb 24 09:34:20 IST 2013".
Any idea why parsing the Full dateformat fails?

```
DateFormat fullDf = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
String str = fullDf.format("Sun Feb 24 09:34:20 IST 2013");
System.out.println(str);
```

The exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
```

Answer (score 8):

```
DateFormat fullDf = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
String str = fullDf.format(dt); 
System.out.println(str);
```

I think that problem was `format(dt.toString())`

`DateFormat` works only with Date values. I faced a similar problem a long ago. Always check [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).

### Update:

As author of thread mentioned:

**Pseudocode:**

```
DateFormat inFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(<pattern>);
DateFormat outFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(<pattern>);

String source; // parsed text from file
Date dt = inFormatter.parse(source);
String output = outFormatter.format(dt);
```

Comment: Sorry the question was misleading; please see the edit. The date text is read from a file and I need to parse it. No way to modify the date generating function.

Comment: @Aczire you need first convert text to Date and then format Date object, not text. so you need at least two DateFormat instances.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line

```
 String str = fullDf.format(dt.toString())
```

to

```
 String str = fullDf.format(dt);
```

Better deal with object than with its toString() because the default toString() may return a totally different value than expected

Answer (score 0):

DateFormat's format function can take in Objects however those objects must either be a Number or a Date.

So only `String str = fullDf.format(dt);` will work and `String str = fullDf.format(now - dateOffset);` with work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format a String with the `DateFormat` class. Use an the date object instead.

Replace

`String str = fullDf.format(dt.toString());`

with

`String str = fullDf.format(dt);`

and it will work.